# C++/CLI String^ to char* 'error: cannot obtain value'

Tags: c++-cli, interop, wrapper, command-line-interface

So, basically I have a c++ code which I wrap into CLI.

### Wrapper:

```
    public ref class Managed
    {
        Native* native;
    public:
        Managed();
        ~Managed();
        bool FooManaged(String^ param1, String^ param2);
    };

    bool Managed::FooManaged(String^ param1, String^ param2)
    {
        return native->Foo(StringToChar(param1), StringToChar(param2));
    }

    char* StringToChar(String^ str)
    {
        char *ch;
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(str);
        size_t convertedChars = 0; 
        size_t  sizeInBytes = ((str->Length + 1) * 2); 
        ch = (char *)malloc(sizeInBytes); 
        wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, ch, sizeInBytes, wch, sizeInBytes);
        return ch;
    }
```

### Native code:

```
Native::Foo(char* param1, char* param2)
{
    // param1 error: cannot obtain value    char*
}
```

Everything's OK on managed side, but on unmanaged I get this error. Any suggestions?

---

### EDIT

Guys, this sample works just fine (I've put up a brief snippet). And I do know several other ways to perform the same thing. BUT! Every method I use doesn't work for letters:

```
String^ "1234567890"   ---> char* 0x0000000 "1234567890"
String^ "name"         ---> error
String^ "192.168. ..." ---> char* 0x0000000 "192.168. ..."
```

Comment: Side note: you leak memory here, because you don't `free()` the allocations returned by `StringToChar()`, assuming that `Native::Foo()` does not take ownership of the allocations. (Additionally, you are in C++ land here so you should be using `new char[sizeInBytes]` and `delete[]`, or just `std::string` and its `c_str()` method.)

Comment: @cdhowie, yeah, this way gives me the same error.

Comment: @AlexFarber, tried this one too. Nothing good either.

Comment: Could you include [a complete example code that demonstrates the issue you're having](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @BasilB My comment was not about fixing the error you're getting, but about fixing the memory leak, which is why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with conversion itself. The full signature of function was:

```
Native::Foo(char* param1, short param2, char* param3, char* param4)
{
    // param3 error: cannot obtain value    char*
}
```

Here error appeared on 'param3'. Changing params order **solved** my problem:

```
Native::Foo(char* param1, char* param3, char* param4, short param2)
{
    // everything's cool
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is to use library functions:-

```
using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

char *charString = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString);
```

Comment: I think you should also mention how to deallocate that `char*`.